# How to automatically update camera position in google maps flutter when widget variable is changed?

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I've got a google map using the flutter google maps package with one marker on it where the location and info of that marker get passed to the widget and changed via a variable. The initial location is set fine, but when that location variable changes the marker changes positions (like i want it to) but the camera doesn't update to show the new marker position in the center of the frame.

```
class CustomGoogleMap extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomGoogleMap({
    @required this.controller,
    Key key,
    this.width,
    this.height,
    this.userLocation,
    this.restaurantLocation,
    this.restaurantInfo,
    this.markers = const [],
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Completer<gmf.GoogleMapController> controller;
  final double width;
  final double height;
  final latlng.LatLng userLocation;
  final latlng.LatLng restaurantLocation;
  final dynamic restaurantInfo;
  final Iterable<gmf.Marker> markers;

  @override
  _CustomGoogleMapState createState() => _CustomGoogleMapState();
}

class _CustomGoogleMapState extends State<CustomGoogleMap> {
  gmf.GoogleMapController mapController;

  gmf.LatLng get initialPosition =>
      widget.userLocation?.toGoogleMaps() ?? const gmf.LatLng(0.0, 0.0);

  gmf.LatLng get restaurantPosition =>
      widget.restaurantLocation?.toGoogleMaps() ?? const gmf.LatLng(0.0, 0.0);

  Completer<gmf.GoogleMapController> _controller;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = widget.controller;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: gmf.GoogleMap(
          onMapCreated: (controller) async {
            _controller.complete(controller);
            // await controller.setMapStyle(gmf.googleMapStyleStrings[widget.style]);
          },
          initialCameraPosition: gmf.CameraPosition(
            target: restaurantPosition,
            zoom: 14.0,
          ),
          markers: {
            gmf.Marker(
                markerId: gmf.MarkerId("test"), 
                position: restaurantPosition,
              
                  )
          },
          zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
          zoomControlsEnabled: true,
          myLocationEnabled: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

extension ToGoogleMapsLatLng on latlng.LatLng {
  gmf.LatLng toGoogleMaps() => gmf.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
}

extension GoogleMapsToLatLng on gmf.LatLng {
  latlng.LatLng toLatLng() => latlng.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
}
```

I want the camera to update when the restaurantLocation variable is changed. I know theres an updateCamera method in the googlemaps flutter package, but i'm not sure how to call that outside of an onTap method.

Answer (score 1):

Just call this function when you set marker position. If you set marker on beginning when you open that page(didn't set marker by pressing button, etc), call it from onMapCreated inside GoogleMap(). Here's the example, search "*lib/ui/map/map_page.dart*" in this link. This example widget is a map and list of button to a location. When you click a button, the camera move to that location:
https://github.com/Bobby-Anggunawan/Jagawana-AndroidApp/commit/13b10832f37578154ba38fc92f68cfb5d2edd5a3

```
Future<void> moveMapCamera(double lat, double lng) async {
  CameraPosition nepPos = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(lat, lng),
    zoom: 5,
  );

  final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
  controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(nepPos));
}
```

Comment: The google map is opened and marker is set on page load, and there's a button on that page (not in the custom google maps widget above) that updates the local state to a new location, and that location is being passed into the maps widget as restaurantLocation. So the marker will update with the state change, but I'm not sure where to put that move camera function because the local variable is being changed outside the widget where the controller is

Comment: I didnt see any problem.. just call that function when you press the button. But i didnt see button you mention. So i suspect that's a button in other page that contain this google map widget. I dont know how it work without know how you arrange it -_-

Comment: And how you change value of  restaurantPosition? Thats the biggest question. You just set it in parent widget like restaurantPosition=<value>? You set that property to final.. you cant change the location without rebuild the widget. And if you do rebuild the widget, you will never run into this problem because setting the initialCameraPosition is actually enough.

Comment: Yes the button that changes restaurant location is on another page and that button updates the local state which is then passed into this google maps widget to show the new marker location. When the state updates the marker also updates but the camera view does not change when i have that in the onMapCreated. So the button I'm pressing to change restaurant position is outside of this widget and outside the reach of the controller

Comment: Oh.. i forget.. google map widget only build once.. You cant rebuild it once your screen show it. Even if the parent rebuild,

Comment: But, have you try my code yet?